The real and imaginary direction in polar Coordination (Cauchy-Riemann equation)
I encountered this question when I was solving Cauchy-Riemann equation in polar form
Here's a note from a book that states:
"The real and imaginary parts of an analytic function must satisfy the
Cauchy-Riemann equations for an arbitrary orientation of the coordinate
system",
then it goes on to choose the directions as $∂/∂r $ and $r^{-1}∂/∂θ$ and goes onto solve the problem using chain rule, CRE  which I(kind of) understand.
My question is why are these 2 real and imaginary directions?
I get that these 2 directions are tangential and normal direction of $r$
but shouldn't it be in the direction of $r\sin\theta$ and $r\cos\theta$ ?  I deduced this from $z=re^{i\theta}=r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta$
Or am I entirely missing the point of polar coordination?

The Cauchy-Riemann equation states, that a holomorphic function in $\mathbb C \times \mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ $$(x+i y, x-i y)\to f(x,y)+ i\ g(x,y)$$ is independent of $x-i \ y$.
$$x+i \ y=w,\quad x-i\ y = \overline w$$
$$\partial_\overline w \tilde f(w,\overline w) =0$$
In polar coordinates
$$w=x+iy = r \  e^{i \phi},\quad  \overline w = x - i \ y = r \ e^{- i \phi}$$
$$r^2 \ = w \ \overline w, \quad 2 \ \phi =  \log\left( \frac{w}{\overline w}\right) $$
you have to transform by formal differential algebra with two independent directions $$du=(dr,d \phi),\quad dv=(dr,-d \phi)$$
$$(\partial_x + i \partial_y ) \ \left( f(x,y) + i g(x,y) \right) (dx - i \ dy) =0  $$
to polar coordinates, such that
$$(  (\partial_x r) \  \partial_r +  (\partial_x \phi) \ \partial_\phi + i \left(  (\partial_y r) \ \partial_r +  (\partial_y \phi) \ \partial_\phi \right)) \ \left( f(x,y) + i g(x,y) \right) \ (d x(r,\phi) - i \ d y(r,\phi)) \ = \ 0  $$
